# An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli, ng

I'm trying to build my [project](https://github.com/jesperancinha/moving-objects-service-root) and suddently I'm faced with this problem:

```
Error: Error: node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/types/matchers.d.ts:713:1 - error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.

713 export = matchers
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



    make: *** [Makefile:23: build-npm] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

It started happening when dependabot tried to upgrade my project [Bump @testing-library/jest-dom from 6.3.0 to 6.4.1 in /moving-objects-gui](https://github.com/jesperancinha/moving-objects-service-root/actions/runs/7766402525/job/21182190590?pr=750)

Node libraries are always a puzzle for me to solve and it usually goes well, but for this one, I can't really figure out what to do. I have read other questions about this, but they seem to be unrelated. They seem to discuss react but this one is about jest. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: This is a TypeScript problem, not a nodejs one. Where and how are you using TypeScript? What does `build-npm` do?

Comment: It is a Makefile command. They are located in the Makefile file at the root of the project. `build-npm` does this: `cd moving-objects-gui && yarn && npm run build`

Comment: ok and what does `npm run build` do there?

Comment: @Bergi, The `npm run build` starts the `package.json` script of `ng build`. Essentially it starts making the build so that the whole application can be deployed and this is where it fails.